# Cox PH model set up when some variables only measured occasionally

Tags: missing-data, cox-model, time-varying-covariate

I am working on an analysis of observational data over 16 years. I'm attempting to conduct a Cox proportional hazards regression but am not sure my data set is in the correct format. I have about 10 variables I want to include in the model and the outcome is death. Currently each physician visit is in a different file. I know that I need to merge all of the data into one file.

- Variables 1-6 are collected at baseline and all physician visits (e.g., blood pressure)
- Variable 7 is only collected at visit 5 and 10 (e.g., depression test)
- Variable 8 only at visit 3
- Variable 9 only at visit 10
- Variable 10 only at visit 13

I want to run models for each individual variable adjusted for age and then a model including all of the variables and adjust for age. Outcome is death and I have follow up time.

Do I create a data set with all participants and all variables of interest-- for example, I would have patient X and all blood pressure readings from all 16 visits... 2 depression test scores and then all of the other variables that were only collected once?

I just want to make sure I am thinking of this correctly.